# Run script as administrator passing arguments

Tags: batch-file, command-line, vbscript, batch-processing

I am trying to run one command as administrator but I am getting error. Below is the code.

VBScript:

```vb
MyPath ="C:\Destination"
Dim objShell
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")  
objShell.ShellExecute "C:\batchScript.cmd " & MyPath &, "", "", "runas", 1
```

`batchScript.cmd`:

```
echo %1
psfile %1 -c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wild guess (since you didn't deem it necessary to actually show the error message): you're using the concatenation operator (`&`) without something to actually concatenate:

```
objShell.ShellExecute "C:\batchScript.cmd " & MyPath &, "", "", "runas", 1
'                                                    ^
```

and you're also passing arguments as part of the command.

Remove the spurious concatenation operator and pass the argument as an actual argument:

```
objShell.ShellExecute "C:\batchScript.cmd", MyPath, "", "runas", 1
```

Also, `$args[0]` is not a valid variable in a batch file.

Comment: This throws error as windows cannot find C:\batchScript.cmd C:\Destination... I used %1 inside batchScript.cmd to fet command line argument

Comment: it's not thoring the error but looks like it's not picking up the value in batchScript.cmd ... the windows is not appearing... even after using %1 and pause statement

Comment: Seems `ShellExecute` doesn't like double quotes around the path.

Comment: okay searching for option to ignore the UAC as we do it in batch it won't be a good approach to have manual intervention

Comment: For the record: what you're trying to do is a Bad Idea(tm). Handles to open files should not be closed forcefully unless there's absolutely no other way, particularly not if you're doing it so frequently that a batch job would be warranted. Users will lose data.

Answer (score 3):

This is not my work, but I found it really a nice peace of code:

```
@echo off
:: ------- Self-elevating.bat --------------------------------------
@whoami /groups | find "S-1-16-12288" > nul && goto :admin
set "ELEVATE_CMDLINE=cd /d "%~dp0" & call "%~f0" %*"
findstr "^:::" "%~sf0">temp.vbs
cscript //nologo temp.vbs & del temp.vbs & exit /b

::: Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
::: Set objWshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
::: Set objWshProcessEnv = objWshShell.Environment("PROCESS")
::: strCommandLine = Trim(objWshProcessEnv("ELEVATE_CMDLINE"))
::: objShell.ShellExecute "cmd", "/c " & strCommandLine, "", "runas"
:admin -------------------------------------------------------------
@echo Running as elevated user.
@echo Script file : %~f0
@echo Arguments   : %*
@echo Working dir : %cd%
```

Use it as header for your CMD and it will do the rest.